# Swift2 : checking the timeinterval repeatedly in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicolor, nstimeinterval

As I have three time intervals one is less than 15 mins, second one greater than or equal to 15 and third one is greater than or equal to
30.In my case am checking only once the conditions.But i want to check the conditions for every 1 minute.Because after the certain timeinterval all the button colors for me should change into appYellowColor() only.Any help is appreciable.Thanks in advance! Here is my code.

```
 if NetworkService.weAreOnline(true) && interval/60 < 15  {

       print("appYellowColor()")
       startButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.appYellowColor()

 }
 else if NetworkService.weAreOnline(true) && interval/60 >= 15  && interval/60 < 30 {

       print("grayColor()")
       startButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
       startButton.userInteractionEnabled = false

 }
 else if NetworkService.weAreOnline(true) && interval/60 >= 30 {

       print("redColor()")
       startButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
       startButton.userInteractionEnabled = false

 }
```

Comment: Polling is very bad in this case. Consider to use a *NetworkService* which **notifies** when the condition changes. *Don't ask, tell*

Comment: Swift 2 is dead. Update.

Comment: @Vinathy nvr No

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible ways to support repeating task is to put its logic into a function (it can be `checkIsOnline()` in your case) and schedule a `Timer` with **repeats** option.

```
let timer = Timer(fire: Date.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60), interval: 60, repeats: true) { (timer) in
    self.checkIsOnline()
}

RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
```

You can `invalidate()` your timer when app is going background and recreate it when app is about to get active.

Answer (score 0):

No need for code, just theory.

You need a **fourth** timer. One set for a single minute (60 seconds). If started at the same time (or right after) as your other three, you just need to check a flag that the other three set. (And if any or all of those three are repeated, have this fourth timer reset things when sending a message in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know swift but in objective c like this.If you call particular method continuesly with particular time intervals you can use NSTimer.

First thing your Secound time intervals greater than or equal to 15.interval/60 >= 15 if we are placing this it will not go to third one because it always true so we need keep like this

NetworkService.weAreOnline(true) && interval/60 >= 15 && interval/60 < 30 when it fails it goes to third condition

```
NSTimer *reachTimer;
//NSInteger secondsLeft;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //to stop the timer you can use secondsLeft
    //secondsLeft = 0;
    reachTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

// This method is called every 300 secs

-(void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer{

    // Build your login here

    //    //if you want to stop timer after 300 sec you can use below code
    //    secondsLeft = secondsLeft+5;
    //    if(secondsLeft>=300) // 60sec * 5min= 300
    //    {
    //        [reachTimer invalidate];// stop timer
    //    }

 }
```